# FloatingActionButton getting covered by listview in the Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, floating-action-button

In the XML below, the `FloatingActionButton` is getting covered by the Linearlayout `ll_urls2` and also `lv_blockedURLs`.

Below the code is how the screenshot looks like. I would like the `FloatingActionButton` to be ON TOP of the listview - how to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/bg_slidingpanes"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_urls2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_slidingpanes"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_blockedURLs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_floatingactionbtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/flbtn_addNewURL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"

        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:src="@drawable/bg_plus"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_floatingactionbtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/flbtn_addNewURL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        app:elevation="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_plus" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see below, the `FloatingActionButton` is missing. Actually if I reduce the height of the `ListView`, I am able to see the `FloatingActionButton`

[image]

Comment: You have to use `<Relative Layout>` as a parent layout instad of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2):

It is not covered by the ListView.
I am pretty sure it just out of the screen. Somewhere below the ListView

Use a RelativeLayout for the outer Layout